# Java How to get call a function of a object from another object variable

Tags: java, object

ok so this is my code:

```
public class First {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o;
        Second second = new Second();
        o = second;
        o.doSomething();
    }
}
```

next page:

```
public class Second {
    public Second() {
        ...
    }

    public static void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

then i get NullPointerException
how can I get "o" to do something?
any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't get a **Null Pointer Exception here** The code doesn't even compile ? You can't call `doSomething()` on `o`. You might want to do `second.doSomething()`

Comment: 1. you can't call `doSomething` on an `Object` variable. 2. `doSomething` is a static function, you can call it directly on the Class: `Second.doSOmething();`. I really advise you to work through some java tutorials

Answer (score 0):

you have to do the casting

```
((Second) o).doSomething();
```

Comment: `doSomething` is a static function and should be accessed in a static way

Comment: still can't tho

Comment: yes ...  & it was called from a static methode (main) . so it will work correctly  ...i tried that ..

Comment: @C.cena yeah, it would work correctly. But you generally shouldn't call `static` methods on *Objects*. They are called `static` for a reason :)

Comment: what do you mean with `it was called from a static methode (main)`? everything is called from the main method :D

Comment: what about variables of Object?

Comment: @YuanKai do yourself a favour and work through a java-tutorial e.g. : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

Answer (score 0):

> then i get NullPointerException

Getting a *NullPointerException* here is not possible as this code wouldn't even compile.

You can't call `doSomething()` on `o`, which is an reference to `Object` and not `Second`. Try typecasting `o` to `Second`

```
((Second)o).doSomething();
```

or calling it on `second` itself:-

```
second.doSomething();
```

Also, `doSomething()` is a static method, and you should probably do

```
Second.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is your answer:

1. You have to initialize the object variable, and then assign the instance of **Second** (second).
2. As some people told you above, the **doSomething()** method is static, so it should be accessed as follows: ***second.doSomething()*** or **Second.doSomething()** (using the name of the class directly, no need to instantiate an object).
3. Why do you want to assign **second** to **o**?

   ```
   public class First {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Object o = new Object();
       Second second = new Second();

       o = second;
       // o.doSomething();
       second.doSomething(); // or the following 
       Second.doSomething();


   }
   ```

   }

---

Also based on your comments below, you need to keep the instance of **o** for other types of objects; when I read that, I imagine that you are working with different types of classes and in runtime you don't know which object you are going to receive as a parameter. If this is correct, then please review the concept of inheritance, maybe this can help you on what you are looking for to do. If not, then what you are basically trying to do is replicating the Factory Pattern [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). This will allow you to create instances of classes depending on the configuration you have.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to change o into other objects